# ORA-02289: sequence does not exist oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, oracle12c

I am performing an insert statment through python SQLALCHEMY. created a base model for a database table. In Oracle, I've created a sequence like shown below

```
CREATE SEQUENCE XXBRIM.XXBRIM_HEADER_INTER_ID_SEQUENCE
  START WITH 60001
  MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 10000
  NOORDER
  NOKEEP
  GLOBAL;
```

Used the above sequence in Trigger shown below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER XXBRIM.XXBRIM_HEADER_ID_INCREAMENT
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON XXBRIM.XXBRIM_SUBHEADER_INTERMEDIA_T FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into dummy_table (col1) values(1);
    IF :NEW.ID_PK IS NULL THEN
        SELECT  XXBRIM_header_inter_id_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID_PK FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
END;
```

In python, using SQLAlchemy created a base model and used the sequence. part of the code is give below:

```
class HeaderIntermediate(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'XXBRIM_SUBHEADER_INTERMEDIA_T'
    ID_PK = Column(Integer, Sequence('XXBRIM.XXBRIM_header_inter_id_SEQUENCE'))
```

tried to insert using the below code in python:

```
session.execute(
  HeaderIntermediate.__table__.insert(),
    [new_ls]
```

(new_ls is a dictionary with column name is key and value to be inserted as value)

I get the below error:

```
nsert exec had an exception: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
[SQL: INSERT INTO "XXBRIM_SUBHEADER_INTERMEDIA_T" ("ID_PK") VALUES ("XXBRIM.XXBRIM.XXBRIM_HEADER_ID_INCREAMENT".nextval) RETURNING "XXBRIM_SUBHEADER_INTERMEDIA_T"."ID_PK" INTO :ret_0]
[parameters: {'ret_0': <cx_Oracle.Var of type DB_TYPE_VARCHAR with value [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]>}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1770, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/risav/Desktop/BRIM_INTEGRATION/json_parser_final_version_1/engine/runtime/parse_json_version1.py", line 105, in process_to_db
    sentence = batch_insert(table_name, row_deduplicate,session)
  File "/Users/risav/Desktop/BRIM_INTEGRATION/json_parser_final_version_1/engine/runtime/db_utils.py", line 72, in batch_insert
    session.execute(
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1689, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1582, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1451, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1813, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1994, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1770, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/Users/risav/.conda/envs/json_parser_ver1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 717, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
[SQL: INSERT INTO "XXBRIM_SUBHEADER_INTERMEDIA_T" ("ID_PK") VALUES ("XXBRIM.XXBRIM.XXBRIM_HEADER_ID_INCREAMENT".nextval) RETURNING "XXBRIM_SUBHEADER_INTERMEDIA_T"."ID_PK" INTO :ret_0]
[parameters: {'ret_0': <cx_Oracle.Var of type DB_TYPE_VARCHAR with value [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]>}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
[10102]
```

But I created and commited the sequence also. Dont know what I am missing

Comment: Why doesn't the sequence name in the error message match the one you created and showed in your config - did you change it for posting, but not consistently? Or are they actually different? Not sure if the config needs to be uppercase to match the data dictionary, or why the error shows the schema prefixed twice - once from the config, but the other one looks odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the schema name is specified twice in your SQL; this is causing the error:

```
INSERT INTO "XXBRIM_SUBHEADER_INTERMEDIA_T" ("ID_PK") VALUES ("XXBRIM.XXBRIM.XXBRIM_HEADER_ID_INCREAMENT".nextval) RETURNING "XXBRIM_SUBHEADER_INTERMEDIA_T"."ID_PK" INTO :ret_0]
```

I would recommend not specifying the schema name in your column definition, as it seems to be getting added automatically somewhere else along the way.

```
ID_PK = Column(Integer, Sequence('XXBRIM_header_inter_id_SEQUENCE'))
```